# Ubercart and Drupal 6 or 7?

Tags: ubercart

At present stage Drupal 7 looks very mature, BUT is see some modules are not yet moved to Drupal 7 or not production Ready. For now I had troubles finding UC_Product_Import and UC_AJAX_CART.
I was pretty confident that 7 was the right choice, but I am getting afraid I will need more modules that yet did not do the move to Drupal 7.
What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your reason for looking at Ubercart in D7? I would recommend taking a look at [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce). It's not the perfect fit for everyone and is very developer orientated at the moment (this will get better eventually). It is where the future for e-commerce is for Drupal so I would defiantly take a look at it.

If DC isn't an option then it's just a matter of looking which modules you require have a stable release and which are close to a stable release.

Another thing to bear in mind when choosing between Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 is that Drupal 6 will have support (e.g. security releases) dropped for it eventually, so going with Drupal 7 may offer more longevity.

Comment: Security releases for Drupal 6 will not anymore created once Drupal 8 will have its first official release that is not an alpha, a beta, or a release candidate version. There is still time, before Drupal 8 is released; waiting some months before to pass to Drupal 7 doesn't cause any problems, especially if some issues for Drupal 7 modules are resolved, in the meantime. If you want to help resolving issues on Drupal 7 modules, you should at least use Drupal 7 in a test site, so to open issue reports for those modules you are interested in.